# How to cater Search from front-end in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have an asp.net application. Functionality required is:

There is 1 dropdown and a gridview underneath. When the page is loaded for first time, nothing is selected in dropdown. The query works like:

```
Select * from myTable;
```

Then when we select something from the dropdown, the query is:

```
Select * from myTable where Col1 = @valueSelected
```

I want to use single query for both the cases, i.e

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
Where
Case @valueSelected WHEN NULL THEN Col1 IN ('ALL', 'PASSED', 'FAILED') ELSE Col1 = @valueSelected END
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
Where
Case @valueSelected WHEN NOT NULL THEN Col1 = @valueSelected ELSE NULL END
```

But both dont work as of now.

Any help/suggestions/pointers ?

Comment: At your last piece of code if you add 1=1 in the else case... What do you get?

Comment: how are you calling this query in application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax use used to simulate `If else condition` using `Case statement` in `where` clause is wrong.

If you need a specific list of values from Col1 then  try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
WHERE  ( Col1 IN ( 'ALL', 'PASSED', 'FAILED' )
         AND @valueSelected IS NULL )
        OR col1 = @valueSelected
```

If you want to have all the values in `col1` then try this.

```
Select * from myTable where Col1 = coalesce(@valueSelected,Col1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

Select * from myTable where Col1 = ISNULL(@valueSelected,Col1)